# Is it possible to check if the android app is in the internal testing stage in the Google Play Console?

Tags: android, react-native, testing, google-play, google-play-console

I want to give the ability to testers to switch API URLs inside my app. And I want to do it only in the internal testing stage(not in the closed testing/production). So I need something like environment variables. Is there some ability for that?

I tried to find the answer in the docs but no results

Answer (score 1):

The testing stage will not affect your app, if you want to support api url switch in internal testing , you have to upload a custom apk in internal testing satage. use [build varient](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) to generate different apk . for example:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {
        debug{...}
        release{...}
    }
    // Specifies one flavor dimension.
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        internaltest {
            dimension "version"
          
        }
        production {
            dimension "version"

        }
    }
}
```

then add api url switch according to `BuildConfig.FLAVOR`